# React-sidenav: TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, sidenav

I get that error when I want to display my nav from react-sidenav:
Error stack-trace: https://hastebin.com/isiguweces.php

My class Navig.js whose contains my nav: https://hastebin.com/kanotegido.xml

And my App.js where it's use : https://hastebin.com/xiyikatice.scala

Comment: the problem is that the `props$icon` is `undefined`. Have you tried to `console.log` it and see if is there some data?

Comment: Yep, the icon was named user instead of userCircle, that is fixed but now I have an issue with history [here](https://hastebin.com/ameveremek.coffeescript)

Comment: are you using `history` in your router? Can I see the code?

Comment: I try to use it but it send me more error all the time:
[App.js](https://hastebin.com/kuzelafena.js), [Navig.js](https://hastebin.com/ijogidulof.xml)

Comment: remove the line `this.props.history.push('/');`. It's not necessary, because you have the route `'/'` as exact path. That's probably what's giving the error. And, the `history` is not a `prop` of your component `App`

Comment: Nope I get [that](https://hastebin.com/ucilowayiv.bash) if I remove the line

Comment: Try `this.props.history = history`

Comment: It works if I import SideNav instead of generate one with `const SideNav = withRR4();` , thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `props$icon` is `undefined` (named `user` instead of `userCircle`).

Change

```
import { user } from 'react-icons-kit/fa/userCircle';
```

to

```
import { userCircle } from 'react-icons-kit/fa/userCircle';
```

To fix your issue.